# Fragment shader for lighting in isometric perspective

Tags: shaders, lighting, fragment-shader, normals

What I'm trying to do is to achieve basic lighting in 2D from an isometric perspective.

Here I have 2 textures that are used as tiles for the ground:

**Color:**

[image]

**Normal map:**

[image]

I have a fragment shader that was adjusted a bit to my needs, but mostly made from this tutorial: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson6

Here is my fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D normal_texture;

//values used for shading algorithm...
uniform vec2 Resolution;      //resolution of screen
uniform vec4 AmbientColor;    //ambient RGBA -- alpha is intensity

uniform vec3 LightPos[3];        //light position, normalized
uniform vec4 LightColor[3];      //light RGBA -- alpha is intensity
uniform vec3 Falloff[3];         //attenuation coefficients

void main()
{
    vec4 DiffuseColor = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);

    vec3 NormalMap = texture2D(normal_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);

    vec3 Sum = vec3(0.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        //The delta position of light
        vec3 LightDir = vec3(LightPos[i].xy - (gl_FragCoord.xy / Resolution.xy), LightPos[i].z);

        //Correct for aspect ratio
        LightDir.x *= Resolution.x / Resolution.y;

        //Determine distance (used for attenuation) BEFORE we normalize our LightDir
        float D = length(LightDir);

        //normalize our vectors
        vec3 N = normalize(NormalMap * 2.0 - 1.0);
        vec3 L = normalize(LightDir);

        //Pre-multiply light color with intensity
        //Then perform "N dot L" to determine our diffuse term
        vec3 Diffuse = (LightColor[i].rgb * LightColor[i].a) * max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

        //pre-multiply ambient color with intensity
        vec3 Ambient = AmbientColor.rgb * AmbientColor.a;

        //calculate attenuation
        float Attenuation = 1.0 / (Falloff[i].x + (Falloff[i].y*D) + (Falloff[i].z*D*D));

        //the calculation which brings it all together
        vec3 Intensity = Ambient + Diffuse * Attenuation;
        vec3 FinalColor = DiffuseColor.rgb * Intensity;

        Sum += FinalColor;
    }

    gl_FragColor = gl_Color * vec4(Sum, DiffuseColor.a);
}
```

This shader WORKS with traditional 2D perspective. That's because in traditional perspective the ground tiles normal map would have a color scheme closer to something like this, just wouldn't be tilted to fit an isometric perspective of course.

[image]

**The issue:** How do I go about adjusting the math in my fragment shader to fit an isometric perspective and work with the "greenish" ground normal maps.

Here's what I'm currently getting with this shader. Light should be equally going in all directions, but it's as if it's going down a slope.

[image]

Comment: It looks like the problem is you're computing your light direction as though it's shining onto a flat vertical quad. So as the visible isometric plane recedes into the depth of the screen, the logical surface you're shining your light on doesn't recede, it just rises in height. At a certain point it rises above the light itself, and all your upward-facing surface normals think they're in shadow because the light is below them. If you want to use 3D normals with a point light, you need to make sure your light direction is full 3D too, not just shining on a billboard.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you, that helped me understand this a bit better. As I understand I need to incorporate the Z coordinate into the formula, right? I tried changing this:

`vec3 LightDir = vec3(LightPos[i].xy - (gl_FragCoord.xy / Resolution.xy), LightPos[i].z);`

To: 

`vec3 LightDir = vec3(LightPos[i].xyz - gl_FragCoord.xyz);`

But I really don't have a good enough understanding of this, so I can't fix it. Is it a small change that needs to be made or the whole shader has to be completely different?

Comment: You need some way of telling your shader what depth the image "looks like" it should be at to the player, rather than the depth the real geometry is actually sitting at (since the real geometry is just a billboard, but you want the player to perceive it as a bumpy plane receding into the distance). I've seen this done by adding a depth map into the alpha channel of the normal map, and using that to reconstruct the in-world depth of a fragment.

Comment: @DMGregory Just to be clear, the depth has to be from the perspective of what I see on the screen? So the top most tiles would be the deepest, and the tiles near the bottom would be the closest, right? So I cannot have a depth map for a texture, because same texture can be in many depths. The depth map has to be generated for the whole visible plane, correct?

Comment: You're very close, except for "I cannot have a depth map for a texture, because the same texture can be in many depths" - you can solve this with a simple addition: `depthOfFragment = depthWithinTile + depthOfTile` - your depth within the tile is read from your map, and the depth of the tile itself can be computed based on its location in the tile grid.

Comment: Just to chime in here: Ray-tracing would be better. Your current solution is never going to look completely realistic anyway, because it will never cast long shadows - all you will see is darkened rear-faces of the raised columns. I would suggest something more like this: Some examples, though you'd still need to convert to isometric view: https://29a.ch/2010/3/24/normal-mapping-with-javascript-and-canvas-tag

Comment: @Colorless how did you solved this in the end?